# Python: a better way to write a if-then block with join?

Tags: python

Is there a better way to write this code? I know it's very simple, but the way I wrote it seems so repetitive.

I'm not necessary looking for a one-line genius code, just some other readable, useful alternative.

Thanks in advance!

```
def __unicode__( self ):
    location = []

    if self.room != None:
        location.append( self.room )
    if self.floor != None:
        location.append( self.floor )
    if self.building != None:
        location.append( self.building )

    location.append( self.property )

    return ", ".join( location )
```

`self.property` is always set, which is not true for `self.room`, `self.floor`, and `self.building`. By the way, this is part of the `models.py` of a Django code in case anyone is wondering.

***Side question***: Is using `property` as a variable name a bad idea? I noticed `property` gets highlighted under syntax, but I looked it up and it's not a [Python reserved word](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).

Here is the complete class:

```
class Location( models.Model ):
    def __unicode__( self ):
        location = []

        if self.room != None:
            location.append( self.room )
        if self.floor != None:
            location.append( self.floor )
        if self.building != None:
            location.append( self.building )

        location.append( self.property )

        return ", ".join( location )

    comments   = models.TextField( blank = True )
    room       = models.CharField( max_length = 135, blank = True )
    floor      = models.CharField( max_length = 135, blank = True )
    building   = models.CharField( max_length = 135, blank = True )
    property   = models.ForeignKey( Property )
    t_created  = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True )
    t_modified = models.DateTimeField( auto_now = True )
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*This first part was an answer to the original question if choosing the first non-None element to append. See updates below that address the revised question*

Without trying to do a crazy one-line or something too fancy, I think this is a pretty easy solution. Just loop over them and append the first one that is not None, then break.

```
for loc in (self.room, self.floor, self.building):
    if loc is not None:
        location.append(loc)
        break
```

If you want a one-liner, here is a list comprehension:

```
location = [l for l in (self.room, self.floor, self.building) if l is not None][:1]
```

A more readable compromise to that last one could be:

```
options = (self.room, self.floor, self.building)
location = [l for l in options if l is not None][:1]
```

@tzaman was right in suggesting not to use `property` for your variable names. It is a built in type:

```
>>> property
<type 'property'>

class property(object)
 |  property(fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None) -> property attribute
 |  
 |  fget is a function to be used for getting an attribute value, and likewise
 |  fset is a function for setting, and fdel a function for del'ing, an
 |  attribute.  Typical use is to define a managed attribute x:
```

**Update**

Because in your comments you mentioned what you actually wanted was any of those properties that are not None, its a super simple list comp:

```
locations = [l for l in (self.room, self.floor, self.building) if l is not None]
```

**Update 2:** *A great suggestion in the comments by @Vaughn Cato*

```
locations = filter(None, [self.room, self.floor, self.building])
```

Comment: or how about location=filter(None,options)[:1]

Comment: That would be good if he actually ended up wanting only the first one. Also, he would have to cast that to a list afterwards as well.

Comment: Of course, you can get all of them by removing the [:1], and if you pass a list instead of a tuple to filter, it will return a list.

Comment: You should post that one as an answer, Its a good one. Otherwise I can add it here.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the `or` operator:

```
first = self.room or self.floor or self.building
if first:
    location.append(first)
```

It automatically returns the value of the first expression that evaluates to `True`.
Also, `property` isn't a reserved word, but it is a [built-in](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) - so yeah, don't use that.

Comment: Slight problem with this, if all of those properties happen to be None, he will get a None appended.

Comment: Clever! But I just realized I didn't want to do `elif`, I should have had three `if`. Oops, so for three `if` the `or` wouldn't work. But I still learned something. Thanks!

Comment: If you want `if` instead of `elif`, just use the `for` loop @jdi described, but without the `break` statement. Or the list comprehension, but without the `[:1]` at the end.

Comment: That would have made it much easier.

Comment: @hobbes3 - Update your question to reflect what you really wanted.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. But thanks for the answer :-). I think I also indirectly learned that I should use `something is not None` instead of `something != None`.

Comment: :) No worries. You should accept @jdi's answer; I'm happy I helped you learn.

Answer (score 3):

Building on what jdi posted:

```
def __unicode__( self ):
    location = filter(None,[self.room,self.floor,self.building])
    location.append(self.property)
    return ", ".join( location )
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking advantage of the fact that `self.property` is never None, and building on Vaughn Cato's post:

```
def __unicode__( self ):
    location = filter(None,[self.room,self.floor,self.building, self.property])
    return ", ".join( location )
```